# java- understanding LinkedList interview questions with nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am currently reading *cracking the coding interview* and looking at questions on *leetcode* and have encountered the same confusion in both places. Specifically with LinkedList problems, which often involve using nodes and creating custom class implementations of Linked Lists. Now I understand what a LinkedList is and how each element is called a "node", etc. But this level seems to be too low level when actually working with LinkedList java data structure and is causing me confusion.

Does any of this actually have to do with java Collections List/ LinkedList api? it doesn't seem so. For example if I search the LinkedList api for "node", I don't even get a single hit.

Take the following leetcode question:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
> integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
> nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a
> linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
> the number 0 itself.
>
> Example
>
> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
>
> Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
>
> Explanation:
> 342 + 465 = 807.

After reading this problem I went to my whiteboard and coded out a solution. As you may imagine, when I went to compare my answer to the solution I was immediately shocked as my code differed from the solution in the first line!

I wrote the following:

```
public LinkedList<Integer> addLinkedLists(LinkedList<Integer> l1, LinkedList<Integer> l2)
```

and the solution had the following:

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2)
```

Please explain what I appear to be missing. Why doesn't the solution receive an actual LinkedList data structure? The question clearly states to return a LinkedList, yet it returns a custom implemented ListNode. I seem to be missing a basic understanding of what was asked.

Question on leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/

Comment: It's referring to the linked list data structure, which only happens to be implemented by the `LinkedList` class. FYI, `LinkedList<int>` is illegal syntax.

Comment: `Does any of this actually have to do with java Collections` It should be the same stuff.

Comment: @shmosel good catch! I updated to <Integer> to avoid any future confusion.

Comment: Regarding `ListNode`, I don't have their implementation, but my feeling is that it's common among older C/C++ programmers to eschew encapsulation and use bare structures instead.  It's a stylistic difference, but Java almost always uses a "hard" encapsulation which some people regard as inefficient and unneeded overhead.

Comment: ListNode is not a Java defined class. The author may be more comfortable with this class or is looking for advanced features not available with LinkedList. Using LinkedList is the preferred way so that you don't depend on external libraries.

Comment: Correct, ListNode is not a Java class. Infact I dont know what it is. Its something the solution uses, yet the question doesnt mention. But i feel like what I'm not understanding is more generic. I updated the question with a link to the leetcode question

Comment: Many of these problems target your low level programming skills. How to solve it without using pre-implemented data structures.

Comment: @Henry I understand that many questions are often low level. But when the question states to return a Linked List, I have a hard time reading between the lines I guess. I don't seem to run into this confusion on Array and ArrayList questions for what ever reason.No one makes a custom implementation of those, they just use them to get to an answer.

Comment: @JavaBeast Java LinkedList uses a private class Node internally. Since this class is private, you can't access it. On the other hand, the LinkedList class gives high level methods that allows you solving the question easily. Since they are testing your skills, they ask you to use your own ListNode class.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the Java built-in [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), except in concept.

One of the things they teach in Programming 101 (or whatever it's called), is how *linked lists* in general work.

They usually start with singly-linked lists, as [illustrated on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), and will then cover other types of linked lists, such as doubly-linked lists (which is how the built-in `LinkedList` is implemented). See Wikipedia article for full list of linked list types (section 3).

In a singly-linked list, the list is made up of nodes, each with a `value` and a reference to the `next` node. In a full list implementation, the nodes are internal to a `List` class (like is done by `LinkedList`), but for simple/early implementations, only the `ListNode` class exists, and a list is represented by the reference to the "head" / first node of the list.

It is this overly simple type of list the questions are working with. If you want to "crack the coding interview" for this low-level of programming, you should study how linked lists work internally.

You could read that Wikipedia article, or search the web for material about linked lists in Java.

Comment: So my mistake was assuming when they said "Linked List", that the LinkedList methods weren't fair game? And I was supposed to just "know", based on it being an algorithm question, they they didn't mean to use LinkedList class?

Answer (score 1):

While @Andreas answer is good, and more at a higher level, my misunderstanding seems to be that I am not familiar with how leetcode works and the device I viewed the question on made the "Submit Solution" part not easily noticeable. My mistake was thinking this was a stand-alone question. I didn't notice the following at the bottom of the page which implies how to answer the question:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interview, the interviewer actually won't tell you what the function signature is like. You will have to decide the function signature based on the interview question (Of course the interviewee should discuss with the interviewer before writing code).

For this problem, `LinkedList` is a black box with only a few APIs to use. So looping the list will actually take O(n^2). Since for each element, you will have to start from the head or tail and move step by step to the desired position. However, with `ListNode` there is much more freedom, so you can loop the list at O(n), which is also the optimized time complexity for this problem.